# Downloading Files From SQL Database Using Entity Framework SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, sharepoint

I am trying to download files from SQL on a SharePoint custom webpart with a modal and gridview. Below is my code for download but when ever I run the code it returns nothing. How can I solve this?

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] File_Bytes;
    string Content_Type;
    string File_Name;
    string RowID = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
    try
    {
        using (ThePointDBEntities thePointDB = new ThePointDBEntities())
        {
            var data = from s in thePointDB.tblProcurement_Internal_Requisitions
                       where (s.Requisition_ID == RowID)
                       select s;
            File_Bytes = (byte[])data.First().File_Data.ToArray();
            Content_Type = data.First().File_ContentType;
            File_Name = data.First().File_Name;
        }
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = Content_Type;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File_Name);
        Response.BinaryWrite(File_Bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Step through with your debugger and identify what is wrong?

Comment: Hie Dale K, thank you for your response, I have done that and I can step through till the last line of code and return no error, from the output I am only seeing this An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException'

Comment: And are file bytes returned?

Comment: Yes they are being returned.

Comment: And what does the request show when you inspect it using a the debugger in the browser?

Comment: Sorry I haven't done that yet. From the inspect tab how do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry that beyond the scope of being able to explain in a comment - I'm sure you can work it out.

Comment: Okay thanks let me try and figure that out.

Comment: Been a while since I worked with ASP.NET but `System.Threading.ThreadAbortException` was the expected outcome from [HttpResponse.End()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end).

Comment: Hi @DaleK this is the error from the browser debugger   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.